# Let P be a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ and let $Q$ be any p-subgroup. Prove that $Q\cap P=Q\cap N_{G}(P)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Task I'm trying to figure out is:
Let P be a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ and let $Q$ be any p-subgroup. Prove that $Q\cap P=Q\cap N_{G}(P)$.

I've seen some facts that might be useful, but nothing seems to come to mind.

I know $n_{(p)} = |G:N_{G}(P)|$, also $|Q| \le p^a$ where a is the maximal power of the prime, but i don't see how it helps.

Please keep in mind i only know the basics regarding Sylow theory when answering.

Comment: This follows directly from the fact $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the LHS is inside the RHS. Suppose $g\in RHS$ but $g\not\in LHS$. Then $g\ne 1$. Since $g\in Q$, its order $|\langle g\rangle |$ is a power $p^k\ne 1$. Since $g\in N_G(P)$, $\langle g\rangle P$ is a subgroup containing $P$ and $g$ and having order $p^m$ for some $m$. Since $P$ is a Sylow subgroup, $\langle g\rangle P=P$, so $g\in P$. Since it is also in $Q\cap N_G(P)\subseteq Q$, we get $g\in Q\cap P=$ LHS, a contradiction. Thus LHS=RHS.

Comment: Two questions. Why is the LHS inside the RHS? I assume $N_{G}(P) \le P$ but i don't see why. Is it connected to sylow theorems or did i just miss something regarding normalizers?

Second question is, why is $\langle g \rangle P=P$? The rest i understand

Comment: Because $N_G(P)$ always contains $P$. This is true for every subgroup $P$, not just Sylow.

Comment: $\langle g\rangle P$ is a subgroup whose order is prime power (do you know how to prove that?) and which contains the Sylow subgroup $P$. But $P$ is a maximal subgroup whose order is prime power, so the product is $P$.

Comment: I don't see how $\langle g \rangle P$ is a subgroup of prime order. The rest of the argument i understand. I'll try to prove it somehow. Thank you. A proof would be appreciated if you have the time to write it, or any reference.

Comment: If subgroup $A$ is inside $N_G(B)$, and $B$ is a subgroup  then $AB$ is a subgroup. Indeed $(ab)(a_1b_1)=aa_1(a_1^{-1}ba_1)b_1\in AB$. And $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}(ab^{-1}a^{-1}\in AB$.

Comment: If $A, B$ are subgroups then $|AB|=|A||B|/|(A\cap B)$. Indeed $AB=\{ab, a\in A, b\in B\}$. Two products $ab$ and $a_1b_1$ are equal iff $a^{-1}a_1=b_1b^{-1}.$ In that equality both sides are in $A\cap B$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hands-down proof making use of Sylow Theory inside $N_G(P)$. Since $Q \cap N_G(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ it must be contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. But $P \unlhd N_G(P)$, whence $P$ is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, implying $Q \cap N_G(P) \subseteq P$. So $Q \cap N_G(P) \subseteq P \cap Q$ and the reverse inclusion is trivial.